# Is there any simpler code for chemical decomposition operation?

Tags: python, simplify

I've tried to write codes for decomposing chemical formula in a form of dictionary as down below.

```
def decompose(material):
    parsed = {}   
    for i in range(len(material)):
        if material[i].isupper():
            if material[i+1].islower():
                element = material[i:i+2]
                if (i+2) < len(material) and material[i+2].isnumeric():
                    num = int(material[i+2])                   
                else:                   
                    num = 1 
            elif material[i+1].isnumeric():              
                if (i+2) < len(material) and material[i+2].isnumeric():            
                    num = int(material[i+1]+material[i+2])           
                else:           
                    num = int(material[i+1])
                element = material[i]      
            else:
                element = material[i]
                num = 1
            parsed[element]=num  
    return parsed
```

You'll get results as down below.

```
example = ['NaCl', 'C2H4', 'KMnO4']
example_list = list(decompose(i) for i in example)
example_list
```

[{'Na': 1, 'Cl': 1}, {'C': 2, 'H': 4}, {'K': 1, 'Mn': 1, 'O': 4}]

Is there any simpler way for this code?
I would be really appreciate :)

Comment: [chempy.util.parsing](https://pythonhosted.org/chempy/chempy.util.html#module-chempy.util.parsing) may be useful.

Comment: Hello, it seems like it might also be useful to post in https://codereview.stackexchange.com. SO is mainly for non-functioning code :)

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you could parse these symbols pretty easily with a regular expression that looks for one uppercase letter followed by optional lowercase letters and numbers. Capturing them in groups will let you make the dicts fairly easily:

```
import re

example = ['NaCl', 'C2H4', 'KMnO4']

# one uppercase letter followed by optional lowercase letters 
# followed by zero or more digits
rx = re.compile(r'([A-Z][a-z]*)(\d*)')

for x in example:
        print({k:int(count) if count else 1 for k, count in rx.findall(x)})
```

prints:

```
{'Na': 1, 'Cl': 1}
{'C': 2, 'H': 4}
{'K': 1, 'Mn': 1, 'O': 4}
```

Above `findall()` will make tuples like `[('C', ''), ('O', '2')]` which you can then process with a dict comprehension to replace the empties with `1`.

Comment: Thank you so much. This is really helpful